# Laravel inheritance of Users

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have two types of users: `User` and `SuperUser`. The `SuperUser` is meant to inherit from `User` and have additional properties and functions. For example, `User` has a `name`; `SuperUser` has `name` and `surname`. However, when I attempt to insert something into the `SuperUsers` **table** it does not insert it - rather an error occurs and it is not inserted.

```
$user= new SuperUser;
$user->name = "Foo";
$user->surname = "Bar";
$user->save();
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, but it seems you don't know what you are doing. You write about `SuperUsers` database? Do you mean table? What fields are there in table in database? Looking at the question we could only guess what is wrong

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek you are right - I don't know what I'm doing! That is why I asked the question... You're correct, I meant table , I'm not sure why I typed database - perhaps because it was late on a Friday.

Comment: @FabioAntunes, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code, I'm guessing that the error you're getting is related to Eloquent trying to save the object in non-existent table.

When you define an Eloquent model, Eloquent assumes that this model should be stored in a table with the same name as model, but snake-cased and in plural form. Therefore, when you try to save a **User** object, it tries to save it in **users** table, but when you try to save a **SuperUser** object, Eloquent tries to save it in **super_users** table.

If you want to have class hierarchy that represents hierarchy of users, but want to have all of them saved to the same table, **you need to define the table name** in the common parent model class - User in your case. You can do that by setting a value to $table variable:

```
class User extends Model {
  protected $table = 'users';
}
```